# Z-Index Set Properly?

Tags: css

Here I have a secondary menu inside the main menu under the button "Courts".

```
#nav li:hover ul {z-index: 101;}
```

When hovered over, the drop down items disappear once the mouse hovers over the slider area.

```
(#slider:after {z-index: 99;}
```

Can someone help me to understand why the dropdown menu disappears even though it has a higher number for it's z-index?

http://www.andersoncountycircuitcourt.com

Comment: You'll need to provide a more complete example. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please also reveal your affiliation with the mentioned website, it might be mistaken with a subtle attempt to promote/advertise it or increase traffic to that particular site ;) Here's a good article on how to use [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `z-index: 1;` to `.nivoSlider`.

I don't know what other elements on your website might interfere with this but giving the `.nivoSlider` a low z-index at least fixes your dropdown menu issues.